# How to create multiple users during installation?

Tags: customization, custom-distributions, adduser, user-management, useradd

Now these days I am working on a Ubuntu customization project. In which I want to add this feature that Customizes OS can be able to create 2 users automatically during the installation. User can be as :

1. Administrator user account named as "Administrator".
2. Standard user account named as "net".

Both users have their own passwords.

Please help me guys.

What can I do to perform this task?